# How to use the dumped data by mongodump?

Tags: mongodb, dump, mongorestore, mongodump

I have used `mongodump` to dump my database of mongodb, it created some bson files under `dump/mydb`

But I don't know how to use them. I tried `mongoimport`, but seems it can't import bson data. Then how to use these bson files? How to import them to another mongodb?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to use **mongorestore**, not mongoimport ... which is used for things like importing json, or csv, etc.

From the `back-up-with-mongodump` docs:

> `mongodump` reads data from a MongoDB database and creates high fidelity BSON files which the `mongorestore` tool can use to populate a MongoDB database.
>
> `mongodump` and `mongorestore` are simple and efficient tools for backing
> up and restoring small MongoDB deployments, but are not ideal for
> capturing backups of larger systems.

You can read more about **mongorestore** in the docs below; I'd take a look and read up on them as they are very helpful.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongorestore

You can also check out http://learnmongo.com for tips and help!

Answer (score 38):

I am using [mongodump](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongodump), [mongorestore](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongorestore) for daily backups and restoring from backup. I have two `.bat` files:
First, for backup, where you need just specify host database name and backup folder:

```
SET host=localhost:27020
SET dbNameToDump=MyDB
SET backupsFolder=Backups

mongodump.exe --host %host% --db %dbNameToDump%

SET date="%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%.%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%"
cd %backupsFolder%
md %date%

xcopy /e ..\dump %date%

rmdir /s /q ..\dump
```

Above bat file create folder with name like this `2011-03-31.11-17(yyyy-MM-dd.hh-ss)` in folder Backups with dumped collections from specified database. In files explorer it looks like so:

[image]

Second bat file i use for retore specified dumped files(here you also need specify database name and folder with dumped files):

```
SET host=localhost:27020
SET dbNameToRestore=MyDB
SET restoreFolder=Restore

mongorestore.exe --host %host% --db %dbNameToRestore% %restoreFolder%
```

In files explorer:

[image]

In additional, i am using windows schedule to automate backup process.

Hope above information will be useful for someone.

Comment: This was really useful. I needed some extra functionality (backing up to a network share). https://gist.github.com/adamb0mb/7191353

Comment: how much data do you think is safe for dump? According to the mongo document, `a small data set` is recommended, but I don't know how to define small?

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the previous answers, you have to use **`mongorestore`** instead of **`mongoimport`**. Adding to the previous answers, when your mongodb is running, execute the following command to restore your dump from the dump directory,

```
mongorestore dump
```

This will import all the collections into your **mydb** database. However this doesn't drop the database before restoring. If you wish to drop the database before importing,

```
mongorestore --drop dump
```

The bson files in the **mydb** directory will be restored as the collections inside **mydb** database. For more info on mongorestore check the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/).

Comment: Strange, I tried to upvote your answer and it didn't change. Anyway, mongorestore needs to be run from command line, not in the mongo shell

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 6):

Use mongorestore. mongoimport works on the output of mongoexport. mongodump & mongorestore work on binary data files while import / export work on json, csv, etc.. (human readable formats)

Answer (score 3):

For resolving this, I copied the dump folder,**dbdump**(which contains bson files) to bin directory of mongodb and executed the below commands in command prompt:

1.
    cd "path to MongoDB's bin folder"
    (Example: cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin)

2.
    mongorestore.exe --dir ./directory name --db database-name
    (Example: mongorestore --dir ./dbdump --db testdb)

All bson files in the dump folder will be imported into your database.
You can verfiy this by executing the below commands :
    cd "path to MongoDB's bin folder"
    mongo.exe
    show dbs;

Answer (score 1):

For mongo version 3 and above use the command below:

```
mongorestore --host=localhost --port=27017 --username=root --authenticationDatabase=admin --db=test dump_folder/
```

Mongo will ask password after that