# How to use mongodump for 1 collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

How can I use `mongodump` to move a single collection from one database to another?

How should I use the command and its options?

Answer (score 172):

I think it's just:

```
mongodump --db=<old_db_name> --collection=<collection_name> --out=data/

mongorestore --db=<new_db_name> --collection=<collection_name> data/<db_name>/<collection_name>.bson
```

Also see docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump--collection) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-databases-with-binary-database-dumps/).

Btw, the other way to move the collection from one database to another is to use `renameCollection`:

```
db.runCommand({renameCollection:"<old_db_name>.<collection_name>",to:"<new_db_name>.<collection_name>"})
```

Here's some related SO threads:

- [How to copy a collection from one database to another in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554762/how-can-i-copy-collection-to-another-database-in-mongodb)
- [How to use the dumped data by mongodump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495540/how-to-use-the-dumped-data-by-mongodump)

Comment: thank you, its giving me following error:Error: missing ; before statement (MongoSession#1) for first command you gave.

Comment: this is the command I am Trying: mongodump --db=DevDB --collection=Functions_List --out=data/

Comment: you need to run the first command from the OS prompt, not mongo shell.

Comment: For those who are dealing with replica sets, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532101/3126973)..

Answer (score 30):

## Taking database (document) dump (backup)

```
mongodump --host <hostname-of-mongoserver> --db <db-name> --username <dbuser-name> --password <password> --gzip --out </backup/location/>
```

## Taking collection dump (backup)

```
mongodump --host <hostname-of-mongoserver> --db <db-name> --collection <collection-name> --username <dbuser-name> --password <password> --gzip --out </backup/location/>
```

[`mongodump` documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

Comment: For anyone who need to restore:
mongorestore --gzip --db <db-name> <collection-name.bson.gz>

Answer (score 7):

Very basic commands for dump mongodb.

1. Dump all collection

   ```
   mongodump
   ```
2. Dump specific database only

   ```
   mongodump --db=DB_NAME
   ```
3. Dump database with username & password

   ```
   mongodump -u=USERNAME -p=PASSWORD --db=DB_NAME
   ```
4. Dump from another host

   ```
   mongodump --host HOST_NAME/HOST_IP --port HOST_PORT  --out {YOUR_DIRECTOTY_PATH} --db=DB_NAME
   ```

Only able to dump from another host when they allow it.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a replica set and you want to use the `--uri` you should use it like this cause documentation states that you can't specify some options when using `--uri`

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb://user:password@mongo-en-1.example.io:27017,mongo-en-2.example.io:27017,mongo-en-3.example.io:27017/$Databasename?replicaSet=$replicasetname&authSource=admin"  --collection $collectionname
```

Then restore it the usual way.

Comment: This is the way to go, if it is a replica set that you are dealing with...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can export a single collection with `mongodump.exe` on Windows 10:

```
"D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongodump.exe" -h localhost --port 27017 -d meteor --collection users -o meteor_users
```

The exported collection is `users`, the database is `meteor`, the host `localhost`, the port is `27017`.

The output will be stored in directory `meteor_users`.

Restoring should use a command like this one:

```
"D:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongorestore.exe" -d meteor -c users users.bson
```

Answer (score 1):

None of them works for me while doing dump for MongoDB atlas. Here is the minor change in the host that work for me

**Dump**

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@host.abcd.mongodb.net/db_name --collection "user_collection" --gzip --out db_backup_folder
```

**Restore**

```
mongorestore --uri mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@dbhost.abcd.mongodb.net -d db_name --gzip  db_backup_folder
```

[atlas-database-tools-backup-restore](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/)