# Mongorestore not restoring data

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I have an existing mongodump of a single collection that I am trying to restore. After running mongo restore, no errors show up and the data is not in the collection. Are there any known reasons how this could happen? I would expect if the data weren't inserted for some reason, an error would be provided in the log.

To create and attempt to restore the dump, I followed the answer provided for this question:
[How to use mongodump for 1 collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347134/how-to-use-mongodump-for-1-collection)

I've created a new database on a different server and it has an empty collection. I've checked the mongo log file and there are no errors, it shows the connection open and authenticate, then disconnect on the next line.

```
mongorestore -vvvvv -u user -p 'password' --db=MyDatabase --collection=MyCollection dump1/MyCollection.bson 
2015-03-04T18:20:31.331+0000 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
2015-03-04T18:20:31.332+0000 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2015-03-04T18:20:31.332+0000 connected to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1)
2015-03-04T18:20:31.332+0000 connected connection!
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2015-03-04T18:20:31.333+0000 drillDown: dump1/MyCollection.bson
2015-03-04T18:20:31.333+0000 dump1/MyCollection.bson
2015-03-04T18:20:31.333+0000    going into namespace [MyDatabase.MyCollection]
Restoring to MyDatabase.MyCollection without dropping. Restored data will be inserted without raising errors; check your server log
         file size: 94876
130 objects found
2015-03-04T18:20:31.336+0000    Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "MyDatabase.MyCollection" }
2015-03-04T18:20:31.340+0000    Creating index: { key: { geometry: "2dsphere" }, name: "geometry_2dsphere", ns: "MyDatabase.MyCollection", 2dsphereIndexVersion: 2 }
```

Log file:

```
2015-03-04T18:20:31.333+0000 [conn874]  authenticate db: MyDatabase { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "user", key: "xxx" }
2015-03-04T18:20:31.342+0000 [conn874] end connection 127.0.0.1:59420 (25 connections now open)
```

The query I am using on the origin and destination is:

```
db.MyCollection.find()
```

On the origin server, the collection has 130 elements, which is what is also shown in the mongorestore output "130 objects found".

Edit:

I added the `--drop` option to the mongorestore command. The log file output clearly shows that it is creating the index on an empty collection.

```
2015-03-20T15:03:57.565+0000 [conn61965]  authenticate db: MyDatabase { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "user", key: "xxx" }
2015-03-20T15:03:57.566+0000 [conn61965] CMD: drop MyDatabase.MyCollection
2015-03-20T15:03:57.631+0000 [conn61965] build index on: MyDatabase.MyCollection properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "MyDatabase.MyCollection" }
2015-03-20T15:03:57.631+0000 [conn61965]         added index to empty collection
2015-03-20T15:03:57.652+0000 [conn61965] build index on: MyDatabase.MyCollection properties: { v: 1, key: { geometry: "2dsphere" }, name: "geometry_2dsphere", ns: "MyDatabase.MyCollection", 2dsphereIndexVersion: 2 }
2015-03-20T15:03:57.652+0000 [conn61965]         added index to empty collection
2015-03-20T15:03:57.654+0000 [conn61965] end connection 127.0.0.1:59456 (21 connections now open)
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate/verify that you are in the correct database (``MyDatabase``) on the destination when verifying the results?

Comment: I've retried the entire process and can verify that I am in the correct database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the issue ended up being that the user I was trying to do the restore with only had the read and dbAdmin roles. I had made a separate user so that the regular user used by the application did not have administrative rights. After changing my user's role from read to readWrite, it worked as expected.

To be honest, if the user didn't have the correct permissions, I really would have expected the log to show an error of some sort when it tries to run the restore without the correct permission.