# meteor: how can I backup my mongo database

Tags: mongodb, import, backup, meteor, dump

How can I make a backup of my meteor mongo database?

If I run:

```
meteor mongo
```

the mongodump command does not work inside the meteor mongoshell

Comment: mongodump doesn't run from the mongo shell. You need to download the full set mongodb tools from mongodb.org for your platform

Answer (score 93, accepted):

First you need to spin up meteor.

Then if you run

```
meteor mongo
```

you will get an output something like this:

> MongoDB shell version: 2.2.1
>
> connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor

Meteor db host is at 127.0.0.1 with a port of 3001.
Exit the mongo shell and use mongodump from your terminal.

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
```

Dumps will be located under the dumps folder in the folder you executed the above command.

You can import your db back to meteor with

```
mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor dump/meteor
```

Comment: I had to specify the port WITH the hostnumber like this: "mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:3002 --port 3002 -d meteor"

Comment: mongoimport did not work for me but mongorestore did ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495540/how-to-use-the-dumped-data-by-mongodump )

Comment: If anyone gets an error like following it's because the mongo port is different than the server, @mkc11 correctly points out to get the port from the mongo connection. `connected to: 127.0.0.1:3000
Mon Mar 17 14:07:26.139 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
assertion: 10276 DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:3000 ns: admin.$cmd query: { isdbgrid: 1 }`

Comment: port has been changed to 3001

Comment: Hm ... I get: "SyntaxError: Unexpected number"
Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, total newb to mongo and meteor. I have meteor and the mongo package along with it. When I typed     mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor, it gives me error:     2015-08-20T17:33:54.923-0700 SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Comment: If you get unexpected number - you are doing this in the console after meteor mongo - you need to exit that shell, that step is only to show you the host address

Comment: For me, this command exits with an empty `dump/meteor` directory. No error.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem it will create an empty directory after running this command. Any guesses why this is happening?

Answer (score 23):

#### If you need to backup a meteor application DB deployed to meteor.com follow these steps:

1. Be sure you are log in into your meteor dev account and **generate a temporary connection link**:

   `$ cd yourapp 
   $ meteor login
   $ meteor mongo yourapp.meteor.com --url`

You'll get something like:

```
mongodb://client-ID:password-3be8-f6c5-50a9-password@production-db-b1.meteor.io:27017/yourapp_meteor_com
```

This link expires in 1 minute, so hurry up! :)

2. **Create a backup** using mongodump command (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-mongodump/#backup-from-non-local):

   `$ mongodump -h production-db-b1.meteor.io --port 27017 --username client-ID  --password password-3be8-f6c5-50a9-password -d yourapp_meteor_com`

This backup the entire remote database into a default dump/ folder.
Voila!

3. If ever you need to **import the db into local meteor mongo DB**, start a mongo shell:

   `$ meteor mongo
   MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
   connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor`

and in another terminal use `mongorestore` command

`$ mongorestore --port 3001`

Comment: This isn't working for me. I get an auth failed error every time.

Comment: This works well. I got `auth fails` error when I was too slow. Or you might have mistyped something.

Comment: I've created a simple script that does this in one single command. Hope this helps :) https://gist.github.com/brugnara/80f980e4e33da7b87408

Comment: For restoring I found I had to do:
`mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor dump/<some directory>`

Comment: after importing i'm seeing two separate database ([screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1f6kyfncc81dwlm/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-21%20at%203.53.52%20AM.png?dl=0)). any ideas how to put the contents of my remote (the appname_meteor_com) backup to the main meteor db?