# How to backup Backup mongo db in meteorjs as mongodump is not working

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

I am new in Meteorjs and i am using mongo db which comes with the meteor package.
I have made one small meteor application using mongodb and now i want to take backup of the mongo db database. I have seen many web sites and still i am not able to backup my data base. Everyone explained the same thing that in mongo db folder use mongodump and mongostore but when i use mongodump and mongostore on my terminal then it displays something like 'mongodump' is not an internal or external source command. Can u please help me in finding out the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [meteor: how can I backup my mongo database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816860/meteor-how-can-i-backup-my-mongo-database)

Comment: what's your operating system?

Comment: windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the easiest way to backup your database (or move it between meteor installations for that matter) is to simple copy the files in `.meteor\local\db`

Then you don't have to worry about all that mongodb dump stuff. Simple.