# How to grant permission for mongodb's mongodump

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to migrate my db over to a new machine. When I use `mongodump` in cmd it gives the error:

`Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating directory for metadata file dump\margin_calls: mkdir dump: Access is denied.`

I know I need to grant the 'backup' permission to allow this but I can't figure out how to do this.

EDIT: I thought this was quite an easy problem for someone familiar with the mongodb environment ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. It's because you do not have write permissions in the directory. You can change your command to:

```
    mongodump --out C:\Users\{YourUser}\Desktop
```

for example. So the backup dump is stored in a new folder in your desktop (change the path to store it in a different location).

Thanks to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37510708/13811514
for the original post.

Comment: Hmm, Am having this same issue but the --out doesn't help. Have tried various directories and so mongodump will create a new directory for the backup alright but still fails on the metadata.json step with Access denied.

Comment: Update to the above. Actually it finally worked when i tried "--out C:\". All kinds of various user directories would not work though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#required-access), there's a built-in [`backup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#backup) role which is designed for this sort of thing:

```
> use admin
> db.createUser({
    user: "backupuser",
    pwd: "12345",
    roles: ["backup"]
})
```

Comment: The issue seems to be in the client filesystem permissions. (`mongodump` doesn't have permissions to create the dump file) I don't think there's any database change necessary at this point.