# How to do a simple backup and migration of mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, shell

This is driving me nuts.

I just want to move my mongodb to a new computer.

However when I try to do `mongodump --db margin_calls` i get the error:

`Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating directory for metadata file dump\margin_calls: mkdir dump: Access is denied.`

So then I tried it with access controls. I made a user on the admin db with `userAdminAnyDatabase` privileges, I then restarted mongod in `--auth` mode and started a mongo instance:

`mongo -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`

in the docs it says:

["The myUserAdmin user only has privileges to manage users and roles. As myUserAdmin, if you attempt to perform any other operations, such as read from a foo collection in the test database, MongoDB returns an error."](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#create-additional-users-as-needed-for-your-deployment)

So I then proceed to make user in the database I want to backup with the role: 'backup'

`db.createUser({user: "loba", pwd: "abc123", roles: ["backup"]})`

And it just throws this error:

```
Error: couldn't add user: No role named backup@margin_calls :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1267:15
@(shell):1:1
```

I've been trying this for days now and I'm beginning to get really stressed out, why can't I simply back up my database ?

I'm using mongo 3.2 on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :
[mongodb permisssion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510504/using-mongodump-to-extract-meteor-data)

You need to specify the --out option with a path

Answer (score 0):

The access control problem you are facing is not of the mongo access. The mongo process doesnot have permission to create folder in your machine. Try running it as root.

> sudo mongodump --db margin_calls

or change the owner permission of the directory

> sudo chown user:group metadata-directory

If your DB size is large, go for mongo [replication](http://www.akashdathan.in/2016/11/migrate-mongo-database-using-replication/). It even defragments the db, saving space.