# Meteor: how to save and restore mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I found this solution with mongodump ( [meteor: how can I backup my mongo database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816860/meteor-how-can-i-backup-my-mongo-database) ):

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor dump/meteor
```

However, I can't use these commands (*mongodump* and *mongorestore*) in my Windows 10 console (Error: typo or couldn't find these commands). Do I have to install *mongodump* and *mongorestore* first? Just want to save and restore my local Meteor.users/db.users and my App-Collection db.mycollection.

Comment: Are those executables located in your mongodb install directory? If so you need to add them to your PATH before using them as you noted

Comment: I don't know where to find them or how to check this. I installed my meteor framework from https://www.meteor.com/install.

Comment: yes, you need to install them yourself. On Mac and Linux they are part of the mongodb installation, not sure how it on Windows. They are not bundled with Meteor.

Comment: Does it mean I have to install MongoDB extra from this site: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community ? Would this installation include _mongodump_ and _mongorestore_ and set all PATH I need for these commands automatically? I can't see Windows 10 in the download list.

Comment: Look where you installed MongoDB, something like: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin. Essentially your question is an XY problem: you need to figure out how to add an executable to your PATH in Windows 10.

Comment: Nice! After MongoDB installation _mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.10-signed.msi_ I found _\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin_ folder and set PATH location to this folder. After this I tried to save and restore my collections and it works! Thanks for your help.

Comment: How can I mark my question as solved? You can also post your answer as solution and I will accept it.

Comment: I'll do that - sorry I didn't get to it earlier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look where you installed MongoDB, something like: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin`. If those executables are in that directory, then you just need to add that directory to your system PATH and they will be available to use a commands.