# mongoimport fails, boost::filesystem error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoimport

I am regular mongo user. But now i'm facing a problem with `mongoimport` command. It shows following error whenever i try to import database (dumped via `mongodump`)

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
error: boost::filesystem::file_size: Operation not permitted: "mydb/"
```

when i tried running

```
mongoimport mydb/
```

Anyone familiar with this or what causes this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the dumped data by mongodump?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495540/how-to-use-the-dumped-data-by-mongodump)

Comment: You need to use `mongorestore` if the data you are using was extracted with `mongodump`.

Comment: The `mongoimport` command will work with plain text such as the output of `mongoexport`

Comment: ohh man! i am really losing it! thanks @Lix