# How to get mongodb schema dump

Tags: mongodb, schema, backup

I can take mongodb data backup but I am not sure about mongodb schama backup.
Is there any way to take dump of MONGODB schema only not the data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use mongorestore... which is used for things like importing json, or csv, etc.

You can read more about mongorestore in the docs below; I'd take a look and read up on them as they are very helpful.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongorestore

You can also check out http://learnmongo.com for tips and help!
or you can visit the links

[How to use the dumped data by mongodump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495540/how-to-use-the-dumped-data-by-mongodump) hope  this may be helpful for you.

Comment: Didn't see any dump/export schema options in the MongoDB link. Did find one item of interest, "mongodump only captures the documents in the database".  If mongodump doesn't capture the schema, how can mongorestore restore them?

Comment: yeah the question was about schema info, not data. even though mongo is schemaless the question is about how to get some of the structure from the DB. even the first record would be valuable if you're using something like Mongoose

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB is an NoSQL Database.

There is no fixed schema for any collection, so there are no functions available in mongo shell to find the collection schema.

Fixed Schema is applicable for RDBMS databases. In NoSQL DB, such as mongodb it is not required, but you can enforce same schema using your implementation logic, if required.

A document in a same collection, can be of different schema's. Please see example below

```
db.mycollection.insert([ 
{ "_id":1, "name":"A"}, 
{ "_id":2, "name":"CD", "age":29}, 
{ "_id":3, "name":"AB", "age":28}, 
{ "_id":4, "name":"ABC", "age":27, "emailId":"abc@xyz.com"}, 
{ "_id":5, "name":"ABCD", "age":29, "emailId":"abcd@xyz.com"}]);

db.mycollection.find();

{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "A" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "CD", "age" : 29 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "AB", "age" : 28 }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "ABC", "age" : 27, "emailId" : "abc@xyz.com" }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "ABCD", "age" : 29, "emailId" : "abcd@xyz.com" }
```

An approach to find the schema

```
In Mongo Shell
var k = db.mycollection.findOne();
for ( i in k){print (i)};
  _id
  name
```

this approach will work for you if all the documents in your collection follows the same schema.

Comment: Even though MongoDB is schema-less, its nice to have a script to setup the sharding and indexing.

Comment: MongoDB now supports schema validators + definitely it's a valid point to want to export and perhaps version control all indices and similar schema-related settings aside from data.

Comment: this is neat but it doesn't do nested structures, just the top level. in 2020 is there a better way?

Comment: @dcsan - you can analyze and export a schema using Compass https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/schema/export

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://localhost/mydb" -o ./mydb-dump
find ./mydb-dump -name *.bson -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

**Explanation:** I'm dumping the whole database, then truncating all the `.bson` files (which hold collection data) to zero bytes.

**Limitation:** Obviously, this is only practical if the source database is small, otherwise you're generating a huge data dump only to throw away most of it.

To restore this-

```
mongorestore --uri="mongodb://some-other-server/mydb" ./mydb-dump
```

**If there's a better way to do this, I'd love to know what it is!**

Comment: Had to do `for /r %i in (*.bson) do copy /Y nul: %i` instead of your second line. However upon using mongorestore, it didn't work. Gave the error `don't know what to do with file` for each file.

Comment: I got it working by dumping collection to `./dump/db` using a uri ending in`/db` and then restoring using `./dump/` without specifying a db in the uri. It did not work when specifying a db for the restore in uri. unclear as to why.

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB Compass GUI](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass) has a way to export the schema to JSON.

At the time of this post, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this by bulk, so this will have to be done for each collection one by one.

From the docs:

> You can export your schema after analyzing it. This is useful for
> sharing your schema and comparing schemas across collections.
>
> If you have not already done so, analyze your schema:
>
> Select your desired collection and click the **Schema** tab. Click
> **Analyze Schema**.
>
> Once your schema has been analyzed, export your schema:
>
> In the top menu bar, click Collection. From the dropdown, click Share
> Schema as JSON.

[image]

Your schema is copied to your clipboard as a JSON object.

See full docs here ~ https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/master/schema/export/

Answer (score 0):

For most backup scenarios, you restore the data, indexes, and other metadata all at the same time. However, for some local development scenarios, I could imagine wanting to only restore the indexes and other metadata so you can create some sample data. (This is also helpful if you are using Cosmos DB for MongoDB RU with periodic backup, where unique indexes can only be created before any documents are added.)

To do this, just make a normal backup and then delete the `.bson` files from the directory.  This will leave the `.metadata.json` files, which have the indexes and other metadata.  For example, on Mac/Linux you can do:

```
mongodump --out=dumpdir
rm dumpdir/*/*.bson
```

Then you can restore the indexes and other metadata by running a normal restore on this directory:

```
mongorestore dumpdir
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76625666