# Can i export schema mongodb without value?

Tags: mongodb, export, schema

I want to export a mongodb collection without a value, I've tried using the mongodb compass but it's not quite what I want

Comment: This question is also useful to me since Cosmos DB API for MongoDB RU instances with periodic backup require unique indexes to be created before adding any data.

(In contrast, vCore instances allow you to create unique indexes at any point. Also, RU instances with continuous backup require unique indexes to be created along with the collection using the Cosmos DB CreateCollection extension command.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that's [not implemented in mongodump](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-825).

You'd have to make a full database dump, and trim afterwards so you're only left with `*.metadata.json`.

On the Linux / Mac / *nix command line, you can do:

```bash
mongodump --out=mydumpdir
rm mydumpdir/*/*.bson
```

You can then import it elsewhere using `mongorestore mydumpdir`.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I've been looking for this answer for a couple days.  When I tried to restore a single .metadata.json file, mongorestore failed ("don't know what to do with file"), but this answer helped me realize that I needed to pass the dump directory to mongorestore.

Answer (score -4):

MongoDB is a schema-free database, thus your question does not make much sense. In principle every document in a collection could have a different structure.

In case you defined defined a [Schema Validation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/) you can interrogate the schema with this command:

```
db.getCollectionInfos({ name: "name of collection" }).shift().options.validator
```

Comment: The question absolutely makes sense. MongoDB's export schema function includes types, but it also includes 1000 samples of values for those types. The question is whether you can do an export without this, frankly mostly useless, information in the schema.

Comment: The [Export Your Schema](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/schema/export/) I would not consider as "schema". That's more an analyze of your data. A [Database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) is a pre-defined structure of your database and this does not exist for schema-free database like MongoDB - unless you create a Schema Validation (for which I give an answer).